# How to use generic to restrict method parameter type in subclass？

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overwrite

I have a parent class named `Teacher` defined as below:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Teacher {
    public List<Student> list = null;

    public Teacher(String id) {
        list = new LinkedList<Student>();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student tb){
        list.add(tb);
    }
}
```

and `Student`:

```
public class Student {
    public String getStudentName(){
        return "student";
    }
}
```

and a child class which extends `Teacher` and a child class which extends `Student`:

```
import java.util.List;

public class MathStudent extends Student{
    public String getStudentName(){
        return "math student";
    }
}

public class MathTeacher extends Teacher{

    public MathTeacher(String id) {
        super(id);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Obviously, `MathTeacher` has inherited the method `addStudent`.
But what the problem is, when I construct a `MathTeacher` object and add a student for it, I just want it to be a `MathStudent` instead of a `Student`, like this:

```
MathTeacher clc = new MathTeacher("a");
MathStudent tc = new MathStudent();
clc.add(tc);
Student student = new Student();
clc.add(student); // I want this line to throw compling error to avoid a Student object is added
```

What can I do? I guess java generic may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it for instance having something like this:

```
public class Teacher <T extends Student> {
    public List<T> list = null;

    public Teacher(String id) {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public void addStudent(T tb){
        list.add(tb);
    }
}

public class MathTeacher extends Teacher <MathStudent> {

    public MathTeacher(String id) {
        super(id);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Comment: But what can I do if I don't what to modify Teacher and Student class?

Comment: If MathTeacher extends Teacher in your original version then somebody might want to use MathTeacher as normal Teacher (it's polymorphic part of OOP). So if you don't want to change Teacher then you should allow people to add normal student to MathTeacher since it's Teacher too.

Comment: @Vico_Wu, just do this even if you don't want. It's the best way to solve your problem.